# Pythonic way to iterate over a shifted list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, iteration

Given a list `L = [('a',3),('b',4),('c',14),('d',10)]`,
the desired output is the first item from a tuple and the second item from the next tuple, e.g.:

```
a 4
b 14
c 10
```

Straightforward but unpythonic way would be

```
for i in range(len(L)-1):
    print(L[i][0], L[i+1][1])
```

Alternatively, this is what I've came up with:

```
for (a0,a1),(b0,b1) in zip(L,L[1:]):
    print(a0,b1)
```

but it seems to be wasteful. Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: Both approaches are completely fine while I (personally) find the latter using `zip` more readable and understandable. There is nothing wasteful about it, especially because `zip` is lazy in Python 3.

Comment: The only thing I'd change is to use `itertools.islice(L, 1, None)` instead of `L[1:]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve your `zip` example (which is already good), you could use `itertools.islice` to avoid creating a sliced copy of the initial list. In python 3, the below code only generates values, no temporary list is created in the process.

```
import itertools

L = [('a',3),('b',4),('c',14),('d',10)]


for (a0,_),(_,b1) in zip(L,itertools.islice(L,1,None)):
    print(a0,b1)
```

Comment: Just tested performance on large lists and seems to be about 15% faster too. Thanks!

Comment: well worth the `islice` effort. thanks for accepting.

Comment: and whoever you are thanks for the downvote, which is justified by 1) explained code 2) performant code 3) accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

I personally think both options are just fine It is possible to extract the items and join them:

```
pairs = zip(map(itemgetter(0), L), map(itemgetter(1), L[1:]))
# [('a', 4), ('b', 14), ('c', 10)]
```

Answer (score 2):

A pythonic way is to use a generator expression.

You could write it like this:

```
for newTuple in ((L[i][0], L[i+1][1]) for i in range(len(L)-1)):
  print(newTuple)
```

It looks like a list-comprehension, but the iterator-generator will not create the full list, just yields a tuple by tuple, so it is not taking additional memory for a full-copy of list.

Comment: a lovely piece, indeed, Agata

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the first and second items with the help of two generator expressions, use islice to drop one item and zip the two streams together again.

```
first_items = (a for a, _ in L)
second_items = (b for _, b in L)
result = zip(first_items, islice(second_items, 1, None))

print(list(result))
# [('a', 4), ('b', 14), ('c', 10)]
```